# Python SSL CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: python, magento, ssl

I'm using the following code to interact with a Magento webstore using the XMLRPC api. [Magento API Python XMLRPC](https://github.com/voberoi/python-magento)

Everything was working ok until we made a change on our web server to SSL

Now I'm getting the following error.

ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)

I'm not sure why the certificate is failing as we have an EV certificate and all browsers are showing this as ok.

My connection string is:

How can I resolve this / over-ride the code

I'm fairly new to Python so please go easy :o)

`magento = MagentoAPI("www.website.co.uk", 443, "myUsername", "myPassword", "/api/xmlrpc", True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python, or better the OpenSSL library it is using, can not verify the validity of the certificate of the server. There are many possible reasons: bad configuration, missing intermediate or CA certificate, wrong CN...

A first step could be to go to this site and let it test the SSL/TLS capabilities of the server: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

It will give you hints on how to solve problems as well.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, thats great. I think our change from the load balancer to Nginx doing the SSL has caused the problem as an incorrect intermediate certificate has been uploaded as SHA1 when it should be SHA2

Answer (score 0):

Python verifies certs via its own bundle, check where it is located by

```
>>> import certifi
>>> certifi.where()
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/certifi/cacert.pem'
```

and add your certificates to the end of that file.