# Qlik sense ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)

Tags: python, openssl, qliksense

I'm trying to connect Qlik sense API editor through Python with below code and I'm getting below error.

OS : Mac
Pyton version : 3.X

ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)

```
from websocket import create_connection
import ssl


senseHost = "HOST1"
privateKeyPath = "/Users/ABC"


## userDirectory and userId can be found at QMC -> Users
userDirectory, userId = "DIR", "user1"

url = "wss://" + senseHost + ":443/app"  # valid
certs = ({"ca_certs": privateKeyPath + "root.pem",
          "certfile": privateKeyPath + "client.pem",
          "keyfile": privateKeyPath + "client_key.pem",
          "cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
          "server_side": False
          })
ssl.match_hostname = lambda cert, hostname: True
ws = create_connection(url, sslopt=certs,
                       header={'X-Qlik-User: UserDirectory=%s; UserId=%s' % (userDirectory, userId)})

print ("connetced")

session = ws.recv()

print (session)
```

There is similar question in StackOverFlow but there is no clear answer how it git resolved. Can anyone help here please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python SSL CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858634/python-ssl-certificate-verify-failed). The Answer clearly explains why!

Comment: I meant this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49257450/ssl-sslerror-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify-failed-ssl-c?noredirect=1&lq=1 as not clearly explained. Still I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Relevant [Mac OSX python ssl.SSLError: \[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED\] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691327/ssl-sslerror-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify-failed-ssl-c?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

```
certs = ({"ca_certs": privateKeyPath + "root.pem",
          "certfile": privateKeyPath + "client.pem",
          "keyfile": privateKeyPath + "client_key.pem",
          "cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE,
          "server_side": False
          })
```

just try with these if it will Help you. Change `**CERT_REQUIRED**` into `**CERT_NONE**`